Remote desktop using only some monitors (right not left)
I have a Windows 11 workstation with 4 monitors. From left to right they are in order 3,1,2,0 (using mstsc /l). They are all different sizes (see image) but have a shared top.
I want to RDP using only 3 monitors. I have managed to get this working using the left 3 monitors using the paramaters:
use multimon:i:1
selectedmonitors:s:3,1,2

However I want to use the right 3 monitors.
I have tried:
selectedmonitors:s:1,2,0

But that doesnt work it tries to put an image the size of the right 3 monitors but starting with the 1st Monitor.
Any tips how to do this?


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
